# django - logout without calling request.session.flush()

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

I would like to create my logout view for many reasons but the main reason is avoid the `request.session.flush()` the logout is automatically calling. That's not good for my application since I would like to keep alive some of the session variables even if the user logs out. What session variable(s) do I have to delete in order to logout the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides `request.session.flush()` it seems django sets the `request.user` object to an `AnonymousUser():`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
request.user = AnonymousUser()
```

Comment: What I realized is if I set the user to AnonymousUser() it only turns it anonymous just for that user_logout view I created. Is there a way to turn make the user anonymous site wide?

Comment: Are there any authentication signal listeners?  In that case I can create a signal so the logout will be site wide.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it by using  `delete_test_cookie()` within your view. [check more here](http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter12/)

Comment: I'm not sure by deleting test cookie you can logout the user. The purpose for the test cookie is to see if the browser is accepting cookies and once you know it does then you just delete the test cookie right the way anyway.